# Getting tomcat white error page when database is down using Spring Session JDBC

Tags: spring-session

I am using Spring Session JDBC and noticed when the database goes down after a user has authenticated the next request will cause, in my case, an embedded Tomcat white error page (500). Spring Boot allows us to customize error pages using @ControllerAdvice or using an ErrorController. I am unable to use these mechanisms because I believe the exception occurs too early in the request processing cycle. I have set breakpoints in both the controller advice and the ErrorController and no breaks occur.

Stack trace shows the exception is being thrown in the Spring Session SessionRepositoryFilter:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:107)
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:134)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:462)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor218.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:279)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:263)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:430)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.getConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:419)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder.getConnection(ConnectionHolder.java:162)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:612)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700)
at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.lambda$findById$1(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:415)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.findById(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:414)
at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.findById(JdbcIndexedSessionRepository.java:130)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getRequestedSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:351)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:289)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:192)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:241)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.getRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:71)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache.getMatchingRequest(HttpSessionRequestCache.java:92)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:60)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141)
at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Is there any way I can customize the error page using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

I remember following a tutorial on this, it looks like it's been updated since the last time I looked at it but should suffice for your case:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

What this tutorial suggests is to exclude the ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration bean in your properties file.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

Or you can add the newer annotation

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Then you define a error.html page using Thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Something went wrong! </h1>
<h2>Our Engineers are on it</h2>
<a href="/">Go Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Save this file in resources/templates directory.

Hopefully that's enough to get you going. The above tutorial has some follow on stuff if you want to know how to display a 404.html and 500.html page.

****EDIT****
I found another similar question asked. Not sure if it will help you or not but apparently having two ROOT contexts in your tomcat instance will cause the custom error page to not show.

Comment: I will try this but I am not getting the Spring whitelabel error page. I am getting a Tomcat white error page, one that is prefaced with 'Tomcat'. I already have a 500.html in my templates folder.

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work as the Spring error handling is not begin performed. I have setup custom 404, 500, etc. pages and they all work in other situations. My issue seems to be isolated to when a database exception occurs when Spring Session JDBC is being used and getSession() is being called on the request.

Comment: Lee Greiner, I guess that makes sense. I mean, if you're application fails to bootstrap, it's not going to be able to serve a custom error page. I think your only option is maybe to replace the error html page on the tomcat server with something else.